# On button click I want to increment the value of text field by one using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, dom-events

I want each button to increment the value text field next to it

```
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1" id="qty"/>
<button onclick="buttonClick()" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="add">ADD</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var i = 0;
function buttonClick() {
    document.getElementById('qty').value = ++i;
}
```

I'm using this code but it is adding value to first text field only after pressing any of the button on page.

[image: Attached output of design]

Comment: what do you mean by adding value after pressing any button? your code snippet worked for me when i pressed add, but if I manually typed a value and pressed add, it didnt increase the new value. is that the problem here?

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Comment: @HishamBawa Yes I know that it works but when you create multiple buttons as in attached image it increases only the value of first text field only even after pressing the second and third button. I want buttons to update only the text field next to them.

Comment: @SMAKSS Sure, I will keep that in mind next time. I'm new here so don't have much knowledge.

Comment: It's ok, also always avoid using `onclick` on your element due to [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the design you've provided, it seems like you want to be able to use this on multiple "items".

With that in mind you will not be able to use ids.
To get around that you can do something like this instead while taking advantage of some dom based javascript manipulation.

```html
    <div class="item">
      <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1"/>
      <button onclick="buttonClick(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">ADD</button>
    </div>
```

As far as the javascript is concerned since the button is after the text input field you can use `element.previousElementSibling`

```js
function buttonClick(element) {
  let qtyBox = element.previousElementSibling;
  qtyBox.value = parseInt(qtyBox.value) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with limiting increment value?

Comment: You can get the max value from qtyBox and check if you've hit the max before incrementing. Otherwise just return. Same with min

Answer (score 2):

```js
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>
```

Here you go:
Implementation Example: 
Html

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the button is only adding value to the first text field, you can give different IDs to each text field with its own `onclick` function so they can be used separately

Here's an example with your code

```js
var i = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

function buttonClick1() {
    document.getElementById('qty1').value = ++i;
}

function buttonClick2() {
    document.getElementById('qty2').value = ++x;
}

function buttonClick3() {
    document.getElementById('qty3').value = ++y;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1" id="qty1" />
<button onclick="buttonClick1()" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="add">ADD</button>

<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1" id="qty2" />
<button onclick="buttonClick2()" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="add">ADD</button>


<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1" id="qty3" />
<button onclick="buttonClick3()" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="add">ADD</button>
```

.

Comment: in order to make the value increase based on what you type in, use the js code @Abdi2fa used. That worked for me

Comment: Hey! This one totally worked for me but I found a better and simpler answer from other user. Thank You!

Comment: no problem. the answer you choose is indeed much cleaner. i just wanted to show how to get 3 different inputs to work like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Hemanshu Dharmik;

You should probably do something like this:

```
 var i = 0; function buttonClick() { 
     document.getElementById('add').value = i++; } </script>
```

I hope this gets your counter done work properly.